# Blank forms displays in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I just converted my [MS Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access) database from 2000 to 2003 format and then created an executable (.mde) file. The executable works fine, but on one form the screen is blank in form view, even though all of the contols show up in design view. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the query populating the form is returning any rows back.

Comment: The query gets populated in the 2000 format version, but it does'nt in the 2003 format. Compared the property settings for both versions and they are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I adventently turned on the filter. When I turned it off, the form displays data again.